# builtins.TypeError TypeError: {2, 5, 23} is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, flask

This is my code.
I am getting a `JSON` not serializable error in `b.start_time`.

```
def rooms():
    rooms = Room.query.all()       
    formatted_rooms = []
    for r in rooms:
        book = Booking.query.filter_by(room_id=r.id).all()
        formatted_rooms.append( {           
                'name' : r.name,
                'floor': r.floor, 'location': r.location, 
                'city' : r.city, 'capacity' : r.capacity,
                'credits' : r.credits, 'amenities' : r.amenities ,
                'room_id' : r.id,
                 'booking_details': { (b.start_time) 
                                     for b in book }
                                } )
    return json.dumps(formatted_rooms) , 200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `set` is not a JSON data-type

Change this

```
'booking_details': { (b.start_time) for b in book }
```

To a list

```
'booking_details': [ (b.start_time) for b in book ]
```

Comment: thanks a lot @cricket_007,it worked